# WPF DataGrid: field value in Edit mode not available outside row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm using a WPF DataGrid (SelectionMode=Single, SelectionUnit=Cell) to show data that has been grouped two levels deep. I've added a summary row below each second level grouping to do some summations. The user can edit a field on each row which value is part of this summation. This means that I want to recalculate the summation each time the user changes the value of this field.

An adjustment might also affect another field on the same row.

The summations on the summary row are bound to the Items collection that you can reach within the GroupStyle element of the DataGrid. Snippet of my XAML:

```cs
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <!-- For simplicity I've only added one summation field -->
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="9"Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource decimalGroupSumConverter}, ConverterParameter=AmountPerTurn}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

As you can see the summation has been bound to the Items property of the grouping result.

The field the user can adjust is defined as follows:

```cs
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Norm">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NormCalculation}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <xctk:DecimalUpDown Value="{Binding NormCalculation, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

As a result when the user changes a value it directly updates other related fields on the same row, but not the summation row. Only when the focus is moved from the changed row the summation row will also be updated.

After some further investigation I understand the adjusted field is in Edit mode (this happens automatically). A field change triggers (raises propertychanged event) anything within that row, but not outside. After I am leaving the row (moving focus outside that row) the changed field value is committed and as a result triggers controls bound to the Items property on group level. And this is triggering the recalculation of my summation (via a converter as you can see).

Everything works fine, but my problem is the timing. What I want is that the summation is being triggered (and recalculated) directly after the user changes the value of a field.

I can reach this by committing the field on purpose in code each time the user changes its value. Unwanted side-effect is that the concerning field within the UI leaves edit mode too and the user has too click twice to enter edit mode again. This is no working solution.

**My question**: is there a way to commit a changed value of a datagrid cell without loosing edit mode within the UI? May be I should bind to another property than 'Items'?

The Single Click-Editing solution on CodePlex didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it's a known issue in WPF DataGrid.

All the Bindings under a DataGrid are set to

```
  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus
```

You need to override this default setting and set it to pdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged:

```
  <DataTemplate>
        <xctk:DecimalpDown Value="{Binding NormCalculation , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Eran, my binding UpdateSourceTrigger is already set to PropertyChanged but removed that from the snippet. Sorry for that, I'll update the snippet.

Comment: @Michiel297 you've mistakenly  placed it on the textblock and not in the NumericUpDown

Comment: BTW how does your GroupItem know how to re asses the value of all items in group ?

i'm thinking that the lost focus on the groupitem is what makes this evaluation.

Comment: thanks! In my code it is in the NumericUpDown of the CellEditingTemplate too.

Comment: I don't know where this happens, it's what you get out of the box. I do know that Items will be re-evaluated after committing a value.

Comment: the question remains , how do you make Items property in  CollectionViewGroup (which is the object created by grouping and is in fact set as the DataContext of the GroupItem control) ?

Comment: I'll tell u , it happens on the lost focus . all the bindings are evaluated on lost focus. then it get's Items property of CollectionViewGroup

Comment: You would need some sort of behavior to place inside GroupItem or do it in the viewmodel. 
on each property changeof one of it's items

Comment: I want to try and write something for you , but please add a complete code sample with ItemsSource + DataGrid which i can simply use

Comment: i did the sample myself. maybe i'll write something later

Comment: I hope you understand the grouping works fine. Even the update of the changed value to the underlying collection (Items property) works well. It's the way the control seems to work that doesn't fit my needs. Committing the changed value triggers Items, but also ends the Edit Mode.

Comment: i understand. i just asked you to put an extra effort so i wouldn't need to waste time writing you a sample.
i know that the expected behavior is not what you needed. did you understand why the sum is updated only when you leave the row ..?
a broader soloution need to take place. you would need to inspect property change events on the items in the group and the update the a property in some why , which would not be Items.

Comment: Ah, I now understand. My code is mainly based upon an MSDN sample with two level deep grouping. Unfortunately they removed it. Do you still need some code?